# Randomly create a matrix with no repeating elements in columns and rows

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to create a square matrix of size (N x N) where elements will be in range of (0 to N-1) and where will be no repeating elements in rows and columns. Also to do this in some random way if possible. I've come up with an algotithm where there are lists for each row and column, containing yet unused values. So what it does it iterates over rows and columns and for each element finds a set of possible values and randomly chooses from it while deleting selected element from the lists of possible values.

```
n = 5
unused_numbers_column = list(list(range(n)) for j in range(n))
unused_numbers_row = deepcopy(unused_numbers_column)
data_list = []
for i in range(n):
    new_row = []
    for j in range(n):
        intersection_list = [k for k in unused_numbers_row[i] if k in unused_numbers_column[j]]
        print(intersection_list)
        new_val = intersection_list[np.random.randint(0,len(intersection_list))]
        print(new_val)
        unused_numbers_row[i].remove(new_val)
        unused_numbers_column[j].remove(new_val)
        new_row.append(new_val)
    data_list.append(new_row)
    print("full array = " + str(data_list))
data = np.array(data_list)
print(data)
```

However this algotithms only rarely succeeeds and mostly fails. Could anyone suppose another solution?

Comment: Are you allowed to use any modules?

Comment: @VasilisG. yes, free to use any

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the new solution, as I initially misunderstood your problem. What it does is generating a random sequence of number in range `[0,N-1]` and then it randomly permutes each row to avoid duplicate elements in both rows and columns:

```
import random

def createMatrix(n):
    firstRow = random.sample(range(n),n)
    permutes = random.sample(range(n),n)
    return list(firstRow[i:]+firstRow[:i] for i in permutes)


N = 5
m = createMatrix(N)
for i in m:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
[3, 0, 2, 1, 4]
[1, 4, 3, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 0]
[4, 3, 0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: That randomly *rotates* each row. It does always result in a latin square, but they are definitely not randomly distributed, making them unsuitable for cryptographic purposes.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
import random

def matrix(n):
    matrix = []
    for x in range(n):
        choices = [i for i in range(n)]
        row = []
        for y in range(n):
            row.append(random.choice(choices))
            choices.remove(row[-1])
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix
```

Edited to satisfy requirements: values 0 to N-1 where no repeated element per row

Comment: works fine, but doesnt fit into condition of elements in range of (0,N-1) with dimenstions of N x N

Comment: Oh I misread that. So if N was 3 you would want the numbers 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2 in your matrix not 0-9? If so, replace with: `[i for i in range(n) for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: I just tested it and it stills produces duplicate numbers. Try using a list with every number you selected and check if the new random number is inside that list (if it has been selected before).

Comment: im sorry to dissapoint you but still it doesn't have unique elements per column 
'code'
[[4 2 0 3 1]
[0 2 4 3 1]
 [3 4 0 1 2]
 [2 1 0 3 4]
 [0 4 3 2 1]]